# I need a great short/side adventure for level 1 - 3

Tags: dnd-5e, game-recommendation, published-adventures

I recently began playing D&D for the first time in 30 years. Last I played, it was AD&D 1st edition. I am DM-ing my step son Gavin who is just now learning to play, his best friend Jackson, and Jackson's mom and dad. We're playing 5th edition rules in the lost mines of phandelver adventure module, and everyone is having a blast even though we've only just begun the Cragmaw cave in 2 sitting(it's slow going with 2 10 year olds learning the game)

Anyhoo - This weekend Jackson's parents are out of town and he's staying with us, and he and my Gavin want to play D&D, even though Jackson parents are gone (2 of the players). I decided to magically whisk their characters away for a side adventure, and whisk them back in time to continue LMOP.... So, I have one week, and need a great side adventure that will further hook my stepson and his best friend.

I'm looking for a fun, short (4 - 6 hours) adventure for levels 1-3, with some action and maybe some puzzle solving that I can get online. I don't care if it's an earlier edition, as I figure I can adjust the encounters to fit the current rules. I would prefer something not too complicated, as I only have 4 days to prepare, and I have to adjust it to 2 characters.

Comment: I think we still need a bit more detail on what *type* of adventure you're looking for. There are **a lot** of adventures (especially spread across *all* editions) that can be listed under the current criteria you've listed in the last paragraph. You can take a look at [our rules for game recommendations](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071) too, as it also covers what's required when asking a game-recommendation question.

Comment: I think he's looking for some hand holding here. 1) New Gamer/DM, 2) New to Stackexchange 3) wants to play with partial party without disrupting campaign 4) never done this before, how would he know how to narrow it down? 5) if I were him I would feel like I just got slapped down. Open this back up and let people make suggestions.

Comment: @Escoce putting a question on hold isn't meant to feel like a slap in the face, it's meant to help maintain the site's integrity. There are a lot of resources, some linked above, to help users understand *why* questions are put on hold and to help them improve their questions. There is also [this](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/can-we-improve-the-way-we-treat-newcomers) meta post for your viewing pleasure regarding how new users are treated/why we put certain questions on hold. If you would like to discuss the situation further, it should be taken to chat.

Comment: Also related from meta: [What's so problematic about a recommendation question having potentially hundreds of answers, anyway?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3398/1204) (I agree the author needs our assistance - so we're lending it - but this question needs work before it gets reopened.)